# Finding cause of crash (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

Hi I've submitted my game to iTunes Connect the other day and unfortunately it got rejected due to the game crashes (it doesn't crash when I'm testing it, even though I used the same iOS version). They gave me the crash log and I've symbolicate it (using the method from here: https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/crash-re-symbolication-5c28d3a3a883) to find the problem and got this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001964fb270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019659916c pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000196472b14 abort + 108
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000196447a38 __assert_rtn + 88
4   Metal                           0x0000000186b93b0c MTLReportFailure + 452
5   Metal                           0x0000000186b6b24c validateWritePixels + 704
6   AGXMetal                        0x0000000105994c44 0x10597c000 + 101444
7   AGXMetal                        0x00000001059bc084 0x10597c000 + 262276
8   Metal                           0x0000000186b6ce80 -[MTLIOAccelTexture replaceRegion:mipmapLevel:withBytes:bytesPerRow:] + 76
9   HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100970208 TexturesMetal::UploadTextureSubData2D(TextureID, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, TextureFormat, TextureColorSpace) (TexturesMetal.mm:253)
10  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010096b4e0 GfxDeviceMetal::UploadTextureSubData2D(TextureID, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int, int, TextureFormat, TextureColorSpace) (GfxDeviceMetal.mm:1722)
11  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010091510c TextRenderingPrivate::Font::AddCharacterToTexture(unsigned int, int, unsigned int) (Font.cpp:685)
12  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010091564c TextRenderingPrivate::Font::CacheFontForText(unsigned short*, int, int, unsigned int, std::__1::vector<TextRenderingPrivate::TextFormatChange, std::__1::allocator<TextRenderingPrivate::TextFormatChange> >) (Font.cpp:827)
13  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100922c54 TextRenderingPrivate::NativeTextGenerator::Setup() (TextGenerator.cpp:208)
14  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100926db0 TextRenderingPrivate::TextMeshGenerator::Generate() (TextMeshGenerator.cpp:294)
15  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100926c0c TextRenderingPrivate::TextMeshGenerator::Get(UTF16String const&, TextRenderingPrivate::Font*, TextAnchor, TextAlignment, float, float, float, bool, bool, ColorRGBA32, int, int) (TextMeshGenerator.cpp:99)
16  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100911620 TextRenderingModule::TMGenGet(UTF16String const&, TextRendering::Font*, TextAnchor, TextAlignment, float, float, float, bool, bool, ColorRGBA32, int, int) const (TextRenderingModule.cpp:20)
17  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100654798 IMGUI::GetGenerator(RectT<float> const&, GUIContent const&, TextRendering::Font*, TextAnchor, bool, bool, ColorRGBA32, int, int, ImagePosition) (IMGUIUtils.cpp:77)
18  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100650db4 GUIStyle::GetGenerator(RectT<float> const&, GUIContent&) const (GUIStyle.cpp:598)
19  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010065108c GUIStyle::CalcSize(GUIContent&) const (GUIStyle.cpp:435)
20  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010095f604 GUIStyle_CUSTOM_Internal_CalcSize(void*, ScriptingObject*, Vector2fIcall*) (GUIStyleBindings.gen.cpp:660)
21  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100238490 GUIStyle_CalcSize_m2752 (Bulk_UnityEngine_0.cpp:17509)
22  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100066c10 GUIHelper_GetSuggestedFontSizeFull_m1719 (Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:33257)
23  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001000a8f84 SignupScreen_InitLayoutVariable_m2399 (Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.cpp:23558)
24  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001000a5e2c SignupScreen__ctor_m2394 (Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.cpp:23316)
25  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001000a5b70 LoginScreen_Start_m2349 (Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_1.cpp:21572)
26  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001003c2da4 RuntimeInvoker_Void_t189(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) (GeneratedInvokers.cpp:12)
27  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100dd09e0 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppObject**) (Runtime.cpp:299)
28  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001006d4f24 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingException**, bool) (ScriptingInvocation.cpp:128)
29  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001006cf1c4 MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethodIl2Cpp, ScriptingObject*, ScriptingException**) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:844)
30  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001006cf710 MonoBehaviour::InvokeMethodOrCoroutineChecked(ScriptingMethodIl2Cpp, ScriptingObject*) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:926)
31  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001006ce6bc MonoBehaviour::DoGUI(MonoBehaviour::GUILayoutType, int) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:358)
32  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010064cd64 GUIManager::DoGUIEvent(InputEvent&, bool) (GUIManager.cpp:315)
33  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010064d2b4 GUIManager::SendQueuedEvents() (GUIManager.cpp:142)
34  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100683d68 PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*) (Player.cpp:1829)
35  HitAndRescue                    0x0000000100487024 UnityPlayerLoopImpl(bool) (LibEntryPoint.mm:235)
36  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010000b47c UnityRepaint (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:246)
37  HitAndRescue                    0x000000010000b2e0 __51-[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink]_block_invoke (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:52)
38  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001963b5990 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001963b5950 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
40  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001963ba208 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1604
41  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018411f7f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
42  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018411d89c __CFRunLoopRun + 1488
43  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001840492d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
44  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d9776f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
45  UIKit                           0x0000000188c46f3c UIApplicationMain + 1484
46  HitAndRescue                    0x00000001000055d0 main (main.mm:40)
47  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001963e2a04 start + 0
```

There are other threads but the one that crashed was this one so I'm posting only posting this. The part that hints crashed seems to be no4; "MTLReportFailure" but I can't find much info on it, while the last of my function being called seems to be on no22; "GetSuggestedFontSizeFull".

Can anybody help me, which one is the cause here? If it's the Metal's function, how can I fixed that (I'm developing with Unity3D)?

Edit:
So I've tested the game after installing it through TestFlight since this should make sure that I'm using the same exact thing as Apple's tester. And the game still didn't crash (I removed the game from the device first before installing it through TestFlight). So I'm totally not sure what to do now.

Comment: Did you test on a real device using an archive or instruments build?

Comment: I tested on real device; iPhone6 and iPhone4. Doing the same steps that they reported led to the crash, but nothing happened.

Comment: Which build did you test? Debug build or archive or instrument build?

Comment: I installed the game directly from XCode by pressing the Play button with the device attach (I'm not sure if this counts as released or debug...). But when I open the Edit Scheme; it shows the Build Configuration as Release.

Comment: That is most likely a debug build - try cmd-I and run under instruments or use test flight

Comment: I tried building it with cmd+I (Windows+I since I'm using window's keyboard) and it build the for Profiling and run the Instrument (I chose Activity Monitor). I did this with both iPhone4 and iPhone6 and there wasn't any difference (no crash where they said). I changed the ProvisionProfile back to the developer one since I can't build using the distribution profile, don't think that makes the difference does it?

Comment: That will be a optimized build. The only other thing to try is a test flight build - that is the same build that Apple runs

Comment: I've submitted the game for TestFlight. I will check again after it's enable.